# Spring MVC not able to return JSONArray object Error 406

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to return JSONArray object from my spring mvc controller. But I am getting 406 error on browser. This is an ajax request and I am using jquery to make the request.

Spring controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/getAuthorizedScreensForUser.do")  
public @ResponseBody JSONArray getAuthorizedScreensForUser(HttpSession session){  
    UserAuthDetails userAuthDetails = (UserAuthDetails) session.getAttribute("userauthdetails");  
   //This method returns JSONArray  
    return webUtilsService.getJSONArrayResponseForAuthorizedScreens(userAuthDetails.getScrnfldacss());   
}
```

I have tried both these entries in spring-context.xml

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>  
        <mvc:message-converters>  
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">  
                <property name="prefixJson" value="true"/>  
            </bean>  
        </mvc:message-converters>  
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

and

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

My pom.xml has these dependencies:

```
<dependency>  
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>  
            <version>1.9.12</version>  
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>  
            <version>1.9.12</version>  
        </dependency>
```

I am running WAS 8. Not sure what is the problem. I am able to return simple object in json format but not JSONArray object. Please let me know in case I am doing anything wrong.

I know there are so many existing threads having same discussion. But I didn't find anyone with JSONArray object example.
Pawan Chopra

Answer (score 0):

A 406 means that your request did not include the accept header that matches the one in the response.  This comes from the [W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating
>   response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable
>   according to the accept headers sent in the request.

I would start by looking at the request.  Make sure it has "application/json" in the header of the request.  Then, make sure you have the Content-Type of the response set to the same.

Comment: I have verified. It has application/json in header. As I said I am facing this problem when I use JSONArray or JSONObject. Any other object is working fine. Thanks

Comment: have you verified the JSON being produced is correct?  Try sending it through one of the many online JSON validators.  I personally use JSONlint: http://jsonlint.com/